# Out-of-memory error while reading very large text file in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, out-of-memory

I've been tasked with processing a 3.2GB fixed-width delimited text file. Each line is 1563 chars long, and there are approximately 2.1 million lines in the text file. After reading about 1 million lines, my program crashes with an out-of-memory exception error.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Module TestFileCount
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the total number of lines in a text file by reading a line at a time
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks>Crashes when count reaches 1018890</remarks>
    Sub Main()
        Dim inputfile As String = "C:\Split\BIGFILE.txt"
        Dim count As Int32 = 0
        Dim lineoftext As String = ""

        If File.Exists(inputfile) Then
            Dim _read As New StreamReader(inputfile)
            Try
                While (_read.Peek <> -1)
                    lineoftext = _read.ReadLine()
                    count += 1
                End While

                Console.WriteLine("Total Lines in " & inputfile & ": " & count)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            Finally
                _read.Close()
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

It's a pretty straightforward program that reads the text file one line at a time, so I assume it shouldn't take up too much memory in the buffer.

For the life of me, I can't figure out why it's crashing. Does anyone here have any ideas?

Comment: Could it be the buffer size of your `StreamReader`? You can change the size in the constructor.

Comment: Also, are you compiling this for x86 or x64?

Comment: Does it crash at the exact same file offset every time? If so, verify that the expected line breaks are really there at that location onwards.

Comment: Are you sure the line break characters are `\n\r`? It is possible that your text editor is more forgiving when it comes to line breaks than the `StreamReader`.

Comment: Why read the whole line? Just get the first char of each line and add to your count...?

Comment: I could be wrong, my intuition about garbage collection is often wrong, but you could try switching to a StringBuilder. The above app creates 1 million objects for garbage collection probably almost instantly. A StringBuilder wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will fix your problem but don't use peek, change your loop to: (this is C# but you should be able to translate it to VB)

```
while (_read.ReadLine() != null)
{
    count += 1
}
```

If you need to use the line of text inside the loop instead of just counting lines just modify the code to

```
while ((lineoftext = _read.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    count += 1
    //Do something with lineoftext
}
```

---

Kind of off topic and kind of cheating, if each line really is 1563 chars long (including the line ending) and the file is pure ASCII (so all chars take up one byte) you could just do (once again C# but you should be able to translate)

```
long bytesPerLine = 1563;
string inputfile = @"C:\Split\BIGFILE.txt"; //The @ symbol is so we don't have to escape the `\`
long length;

using(FileStream stream = File.Open(inputFile, FileMode.Open)) //This is the C# equivilant of the try/finally to close the stream when done.
{
    length = stream.Length;
}

Console.WriteLine("Total Lines in {0}: {1}", inputfile, (length / bytesPerLine ));
```

Comment: If anyone who has more VB experience than me wants to edit my code and "VB-ify" it, go ahead.

Comment: I tried out your Filestream solution and it works great for getting a line count. Thanks!

Comment: As a sanity check you can do `if (length Mod bytesPerLine <> 0) then ''do something here to show the error`. What that does is it will let you know if there is any remainder from your `length / bytesPerLine` operation, because you are doing intiger division any remainder is truncated and you need to use `Mod` to get the remainder. (for example `11 / 4 = 2` and `11 Mod 4 = 3`). The C# version of this operator is `%`

Comment: The length was 3279546588. Using 1593 for BytesPerLine, the total lines are 2098238 and the remainder is 594.

Comment: If the lines are truely 1593 for every line your remainder should be 1591, 1592, or 0 (if there is no `\r\n` on the last line, if there is no `\n`, or if the last line matches the other lines). Are you sure you included the line ending characters in your 1593 count? Also are you sure ***EVERY*** line is 1593 long?

Comment: Also [`3279546588 Mod 1593` is `849` not `594`](http://ideone.com/93VCcb), are you sure those are the correct numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ReadAsync, or you can use DiscardBufferedData(but this slow )

```
Dim inputfile As String = "C:\Example\existingfile.txt" 
    Dim result() As String 
    Dim builder As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

    Try
        Using reader As StreamReader = File.OpenText(inputfile)
            ReDim result(reader.BaseStream.Length)
            Await reader.ReadAsync(result, 0, reader.BaseStream.Length)
        End Using 

        For Each str As String In result
            builder.Append(str)         
        Next
      Dim count as Integer=builder.Count()
       Console.WriteLine("Total Lines in " & inputfile & ": " & count)
    Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Sorry - I should've mentioned that I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and .NET 3.0. Which means I can't use the StreamReader ReadAsync method.